# Cartoon (broadcasted in India around 2000s) where people fused with companion animals

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

There was this show I used to watch on Jetix, in India, around the 2000s. The lead was a boy and wore a red shirt, or there was something red about him. People used to fuse with their companion animals. This boy fused with a monkey and transformed into a huge King-Kong like thing. The villain had a cockatoo and when he fused with him it was a huge legged bird with wings. The lead boy had a red transformation theme color and this villain had an off-yellow theme. Unfortunately I don't remember much now, please help me find it.

Comment: One of the Digimon series?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Sci-Fi Stackexchange! This seems like a very interesting question and I hope someone comes along soon to answer it. While you wait, feel free to checkout the [tour] and have a look at the [help]!

Comment: @Jenayah No, it was not a Digimon franchise. The animals were normal animals, apes birds etc.

Comment: Possibly useful, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Jetix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it maybe [Kong: The Animated Series (2001)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kong:_The_Animated_Series)?

The way I remember it, there was 3 protagonists, and the main character could fuse his mind with his King Kong companion whenever they needed to fight huge monsters, by using some kind of device if I remember.

Similarly, he could also fuse the kong into himself whenever it was inconvenient (like when they had to travel by vehicle, since the huge kong couldn't get in).

Here's a poster below:

[image: A poster depicting the animated series named Kong. On it, you can notice the 4 protagonists: a black haired young man, a muscled carrot haired guy, and a red haired woman dressed in a somewhat tribal way. Behind them stands a giant sized kong]

There aren't much similarities beside that, but I thought I'd post it just in case.

Comment: As a plus, a cockatoo does show up as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kong:_The_Animated_Series. And Jetix did air it.

Comment: You got it! I found the entire channel https://www.youtube.com/c/KONGTheAnimatedSeriesOfficialChannel

Comment: @AdityaPrakash Thank you for the question. I actually forgot about this show until I read your question.